using a backup & restore to optimize posgresql
first, please forgive my ignorance as I'm no SQL expert. I have an application that uses postgres and we have performance issues with using the UI. All the support team tells us is that we need to take a DB backup and restore it in order to improve performance.
We have autovacuum enabled on the database and could run a full vacuum analyse (I believe this would address any temp tables that autovacuum ignores?)
Is doing a backup/restore really a thing that's necessary to maintain a DB or am I getting fobbed off? does anyone know of resources where I could better educate myself to actually getting to the bottom of the cause?
